# Name query in SQL/SOQL with " ' " as a part of the name

Tags: sql, soql

I need to write a soql/sql query which needs to look up for a name that has an apostrophes in it, Like shaquel o'Neil. The problem is that the where clauses dops the Neil part as that is considered as the end of the search criteria.

Any suggestions how to work this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most SQL you would quote `'` by doubling it to `''`. But afaik you have to escape it with an `\` in SOQL - so you check for `'shaquel o\'Neil'` in your testcase.

I checked it - as I thought, in SOQL you escape with an `\`. Here is an list of all SOQL-special-chars:

```
   \n  New line
   \r  Carriage return
   \t  Tab
   \b  Bell
   \f  Form feed
   \"  One double-quote character
   \'  One single-quote character
   \\  Backslash
```

(Source: [Quoted String Escape Sequences](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm) )